# Continous appending of data on existing tabular data file (CSV, parquet) using PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, append, hdfs

For a project I need to append frequently but on a non-periodic way about one thousand or more data files (tabular data) on one existing CSV or parquet file with same schema in Hadoop/HDFS (master=yarn). At the end, I need to be able to do some filtering on the result file - to extract subset of data.

One dummy file may look like this (very simple example):

```
id,uuid,price
1,16c533c3-c191-470c-97d9-e1e01ccc3080,46159
2,6bb0917b-2414-4b24-85ca-ae2c2713c9a0,50222
3,7b1fa3f9-2db2-4d93-a09d-ca6609cfc834,74591
4,e3a3f874-380f-4c89-8b3e-635296a70d76,91026
5,616dd6e8-5d05-4b07-b8f2-7197b579a058,73425
6,23e77a21-702d-4c87-a69c-b7ace0626616,34874
7,339e9a7f-efb1-4183-ac32-d365e89537bb,63317
8,fee09e5f-6e16-4d4f-abd1-ecedb1b6829c,6642
9,2e344444-35ee-47d9-a06a-5a8bc01d9eab,55931
10,d5cba8d6-f0e1-49c8-88e9-2cd62cde9737,51792
```

Number of rows may vary between 10 and about 100000

On user request, all input files copied in a source folder should be ingested by an ETL pipeline and appended at the end of **one single CSV/parquet file** or any other appropriate file format (no DB). Data from a single input file may be spread over one, two or more partitions.

Because the input data files may all have different number of rows, I am concerned about getting partitions with different sizes in the resulting CSV/parquet file. Sometimes all the data may be append in one new file. Sometimes the data is so big that several files are appended.
And because input files may be appended a lot of time from different users and different sources, I am also concerned that the result CSV/parquet may contains too much part-files for the namenode to handle them.

I have done some small test appending data on existing CSV / parquet files and noticed that for each appending, a new file was generated - for example:
`df.write.mode('append').csv('/user/applepy/pyspark_partition/uuid.csv')`
will append the new data as a new file in the file 'uuid.csv' (which is actually a directory generated by pyspark containing all pieces of appended data).

Doing some load tests based on real conditions, I quickly realized that I was generating A LOT of files (several 10-thousands). At some point I got so much files that PySpark was unable to simple count the number of rows (NameNode memory overflow).

So I wonder how to solve this problem. What would be the best practice here? Read the whole file, append the data chunk, same the data in a new file doesn't seems to be very efficient here.

Comment: Please add code snippets for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

> NameNode memory overflow

Then increase the heapsize of the namenode

> quickly realized that I was generating A LOT of files

HDFS write operations almost never append to single files. They append "into a directory", and create new files, yes.

From Spark, you can use `coalesce` and `repartition` to create larger writer batches.

As you'd mentioned, you wanted parquet, so write that then. That'll cause you to have even smaller file sizes in HDFS.

> or any other appropriate file format (no DB)

HDFS is not really the appropriate tool for this. Clickhouse, Druid, and Pinot are the current real time ingest / ETL tools being used, especially when data is streamed in "non periodically" from Kafka